# $x\in Ext(B_X)$ has the Kadec property, implies that the slices form a neighborhood base of the norm topology

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This is question 3.87 from Fabian's *Functional Analysis and Infinite-Dimensional Geometry.* The result is credited to Lin and Troyanski. Where on the net can I read a proof of this lemma? Any help would be appreciated.

**Definition:** The book defines a slice of a subset $C$ of a Banach space $X$, to be a nonempty intersection with an open half space of $X$.

**Lemma:** Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $x$ be an extreme point for its unit ball. Assume that the relative norm and the weak topology coincide at $x$. Show that the slices form a neighborhood base of the norm topology.

**EDIT:** The book advices to consider the point $j(x)$, where $j$ is the naturall isometry to the by-dual and prove that it is an extreme point for the unit ball there. To this end assume $j(x)$ is not extreme, i.e. $j(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2), x_i\in B_{X^{**}}$

Now by a geometric argument show that the relative $\omega^\ast$, and the relative norm topologies for $B_{X^{**}}$ coincide at $x_i$ and so forth.

**p.s.** I believe the statement in the last sentence is the essence of the question and of potential interest to this community. At least it wasn't getting any attention on Math.SE, hence I asked them to migrate it here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any own work on this? -- It would have been nice to make sure that you copy the hint correctly... 1. It must be the relative weak\*-topology of $B_{X^{\ast\ast}}$ (not the weak topology) at $x_i$ that coincides with the relative norm topology. 2. There is no reason for the $x_i$ to be extremal points of $B_{X^{**}}$. 3. An explanation of the word "slices" might help for those who don't have the book, and, finally, 4. the name is Goldstine, not Goldstein.

Comment: I believe the paper you seek is $$ $$ MR0928972 (89e:46016) Reviewed 
Lin, Bor-Luh(1-IA); Lin, Pei-Kee(1-MEMP); Troyanski, S. L.(BG-SOFI)
Characterizations of denting points. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 102 (1988), no. 3, 526–528. 
46B20 (52A07)